# Script for executing parameters as commands on all directory files

Tags: bash

Im wondering how to make this script work:

```
for f in *.php
do
    for c in seq 1 $#
    do
            eval `eval echo \$$c`
    done
done
```

The main idea of the script y to execute all commands passed to the script on every file, for example:

```
bash script.sh "grep text \$f" "echo \"Done!\""
```

Should be the same as:

```
for f in *.php
do
     grep text $f
     echo "Done!"
done
```

I think it's pretty simple but I've been stuck here for long
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it work like this:

```
for f in *.php
do
  for arg
  do
    eval "$arg"
  done
done
```

A more common (and safer) approach would be

```
find *.php -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} "$@"
```

which could be run as `./yourscript grep text {}`, but it doesn't allow arbitrary shell constructs.

Answer (score 1):

The following simple recipe in your bash script should work.

```
for arg in "$@"
do
    find . -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -n1 -0 -i $arg {}
done
```